# using HTACCESS RewriteCondition so that index.php can only be accessed ONLY when www.example.com is entered

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have been trying to find a way to redirect the user to the index page only when the website is entered without an extension:

Please see the below example:

When the user types in localhost, I want them to be redirected to -> localhost/index.php

BUT...

When the user enters localhost/index.php, I want them to be redirected to -> localhost/user.php?id=index.php

**I tried below with no luck:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost
  RewriteRule (.*) /index.php [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Please let me know if I'm going about this the right way or if there are other ways I should go about solving this problem.

Comment: What should happen when user enters `localhost/style.css` ?